# Can't turn on third monitor Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I would like to work on 3 full hd monitors. In Displays I can see all 3 monitors but one is turn off. When I'm trying to turn on third monitor Apply button disappears. It is on fresh ubuntu. I' using Intel® UHD Graphics 630 on i5-9600K. This card support 3 monitors. [intel support page](https://www.intel.pl/content/www/pl/pl/support/articles/000025672/graphics-drivers.html)

[Displays settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtvBl.png)
xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Your graphics processor probably don't have resources to run three screens.

Comment: Soren A is probably right, can you include the graphic card you're using in the question?

Comment: I'm using Intel® UHD Graphics 630 on i5-9600K. This card support 3 monitors.